# Java: Making Circle with a radius and alternating colors with recursion

Tags: recursion, javafx

I'm trying to get my JaxaFX program to make circle with alternating color when the user enters a radius and come out like this (with my alternating colors being forest green and red):

[image]

But its only coming out as forest green

[image]

```
public class App extends Application {

    
    private Pane centerpane;            // center pane
    private TextField enterTextField;   // text field for user to enter radius of circle
    private double radius;                  // order for recursion
    public Color color = Color.FORESTGREEN;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        BorderPane outerpane = new BorderPane();
        
        //CREATE the CENTER PANE
        centerpane = new Pane();
        centerpane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTBLUE,null,null)));
        outerpane.setCenter(centerpane);
        
        
        
        //CREATE BOTTOM PANE AS HBOX OF LABEL , TEXTFIELD, AND START BUTTOM
        HBox bottompane = new HBox (20);
        bottompane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        bottompane.setPadding(new Insets(25,25,25,25));
        Label label = new Label ("Enter radius of largest cirlce: ");
        enterTextField = new TextField();
        Button startButton = new Button("Start");
        startButton.setOnAction(event -> makeCircles());
        bottompane.getChildren().add(label);
        bottompane.getChildren().add(enterTextField);
        bottompane.getChildren().add(startButton);
        outerpane.setBottom(bottompane);
        
        var scene = new Scene(outerpane, 600, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        
    }
    //Event handler for Start button gets radius, 
    // and calls recursive display
    public void makeCircles()
    {
        //clear the center pane after every use
        centerpane.getChildren().clear();
        try
        {
            radius = Double.parseDouble(enterTextField.getText());
            
            if((radius*2 <= centerpane.getWidth()) && (radius*2 <= centerpane.getHeight()))
            {
                
                displayCircles(radius,color);
                
            }else
            {
                showAlert("Circle does not fit in thec center pane ");
            }
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            showAlert("Invalid input");
        }

    }
    //Display the Circle with recursion
    public void displayCircles(double radius, Color color)
    {
        //When the base case radius is 0 it stops
        if(radius > 0)
        {
           //Displays circle
           Circle circle = new Circle(centerpane.getWidth()/2,centerpane.getHeight()/2,radius);
           circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
           circle.setFill(color);
           centerpane.getChildren().add(circle);
        }
        else // recursive case 
        {
            Color nextColor;
            if(color.equals(Color.FORESTGREEN)){
                nextColor = Color.RED;
            }
            else{
                nextColor = Color.FORESTGREEN;
            }
            displayCircles(radius - 10, nextColor);
        }
    }
     public void showAlert(String message)
     {
         Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
         alert.setTitle("Error");
         alert.setHeaderText(null);
         alert.setContentText(message);
         alert.showAndWait();
     }
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

i can't seem to get it to alternate colors

Comment: You could probably accomplish this using a single circle painted using a [radial gradient with stops](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/RadialGradient.html) on [CycleMethod.REPEAT](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/CycleMethod.html#REPEAT).

Comment: @jewelsea, I just posted my answer and then saw your comment :) Using gradients is exactly what I thought.

Comment: Off-topic, but green and red are a really bad choice of colors in UI design. Something like 5% of some populations are unable to distinguish between those colors.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few issues here to fix.

First, with the recursion. The base case you wrote for the `displayCircles` method, `radius > 0` is not what you want. You want to keep adding circles *for as long* as radius > 0, so you want to end when the radius isn't bigger than 0. In other words, your base case should be `radius <= 0`.

Okay, if we fix that and run the code, we see nothing. That's because currently only in the base case is a circle created. In reality, we want to create a circle every time to get the result you're looking for.

So here's the modified `displayCircles` code:

```java
public void displayCircles(double radius, Color color)
    {
        //When the base case radius is 0 it stops, otherwise run again.
        if(radius > 0)
        {
            // Create and add the circle to UI
            Circle circle = new Circle(centerpane.getWidth()/2,centerpane.getHeight()/2,Math.max(0, radius));
            circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            circle.setFill(color);
            centerpane.getChildren().add(circle);
            
            // Recursively create the next circle.
            Color nextColor;
            if(color.equals(Color.FORESTGREEN)){
                nextColor = Color.RED;
            }
            else{
                nextColor = Color.FORESTGREEN;
            }
            displayCircles(radius - 10, nextColor);
        }
    }
```

And the output:
[image: Successful output]

I assume this is for school, but in the off chance it isn't it would be better to use a for-loop to create the circles as recursion is overkill here.

Answer (score 3):

I agree to what @Zev G mentioned. Using recursive is an overkill. You can achieve the same result with a simple while loop as below:

```
public void displayCircles(double radius) {
    double r = radius;
    boolean isForestGreen = true;
    double cX = centerpane.getWidth() / 2;
    double cY = centerpane.getHeight() / 2;
    //When the base case radius is 0 it stops
    while (r > 0) {
        //Displays circle
        Circle circle = new Circle(cX, cY, r);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        circle.setFill(isForestGreen ? Color.FORESTGREEN : Color.RED);
        centerpane.getChildren().add(circle);

        // Alternate the color
        isForestGreen = !isForestGreen;

        // Decrease the radius
        r = r - 10;
    }
}
```

If your exercise is NOT about using multiple circles but to achieve the **final pattern**, then you can try the below approach. In the below approach you just style the circle to mimic the pattern ( that way you can just use only one circle).

In the below code, adjust the `gap` value for the thickness of each circle.

```
public void displayCircles(double radius) {
    double onePx = 100/radius; // Formula for 1px length for given radius
    double gap = 10; // Required Gap between each circle in pixels
    Circle circle = new Circle(centerpane.getWidth() / 2, centerpane.getHeight() / 2, radius);
    circle.setStyle("-fx-fill:radial-gradient(focus-angle 0deg , focus-distance 0% , center 50% 50% , radius "+(onePx * gap)+"% , repeat, #228B22 50% , #FF0000 50% )");
    centerpane.getChildren().add(circle);
}
```

Below is the output and  the complete code for the demo (when using radial gradient with only one circle) :

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {
    Circle circle;
    Pane centerpane;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        BorderPane outerpane = new BorderPane();

        //CREATE the CENTER PANE
        circle = new Circle(0);
        centerpane = new Pane(circle);
        centerpane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTBLUE, null, null)));
        outerpane.setCenter(centerpane);
        circle.centerXProperty().bind(centerpane.widthProperty().divide(2));
        circle.centerYProperty().bind(centerpane.heightProperty().divide(2));

        //CREATE BOTTOM PANE AS HBOX OF LABEL , TEXTFIELD, AND START BUTTOM
        HBox bottompane = new HBox(20);
        bottompane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        bottompane.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

        Label label = new Label("Enter radius of largest cirlce: ");
        TextField enterTextField = new TextField();
        Button startButton = new Button("Start");
        startButton.setOnAction(event -> updateCircle(enterTextField.getText()));
        bottompane.getChildren().add(label);
        bottompane.getChildren().add(enterTextField);
        bottompane.getChildren().add(startButton);
        outerpane.setBottom(bottompane);

        var scene = new Scene(outerpane, 600, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void updateCircle(String r) {
        try {
            double radius = Double.parseDouble(r);
            if ((radius * 2 <= centerpane.getWidth()) && (radius * 2 <= centerpane.getHeight())) {
                double onePx = 100 / radius; // Formula for 1px length for given radius
                double gap = 10; // Required Gap between each circle in pixels
                circle.setRadius(radius);
                circle.setStyle("-fx-fill:radial-gradient(focus-angle 0deg , focus-distance 0% , center 50% 50% , radius " + (onePx * gap) + "% , repeat, #228B22 50% , #FF0000 50% )");

        // Uncomment the below, to use the API method
        /*
            double eachPx = 1 / radius;
            Stop forestGreen = new Stop(.5, Color.valueOf("#228B22"));
            Stop red = new Stop(.5, Color.valueOf("#FF0000"));
            circle.setFill(new RadialGradient(0, 0, .5, .5, (eachPx * gap), true, CycleMethod.REPEAT, forestGreen, red));
       */

            } else {
                showAlert("Circle does not fit in the center pane ");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            showAlert("Invalid input");
        }
    }

    public void showAlert(String message) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText(message);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps easier (and more flexible) to do this in Java instead of CSS: `List<Stop> stops = ...` which can be populated dynamically and `circle.setFill(new RadialGradient(...))`.

Comment: @James_D updated my answer to include the Java way as well. But some how I feel using CSS way is a bit self explanatory ;).